# If for some $\phi$ measurable function, if $\phi f_n \to g$ and $f_n\to f$ then $g=\phi f$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Omega,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$- finite measure space and let $\phi : X \to \mathbb{C}$ be an $\Omega$- measurable function. Then show that if $\phi f_n \to g$ and $f_n\to f$ then $g=\phi f$.(all $f_n \in L^2(\mu)$ and the convergence above are in $L^2$ sence).

Comment: Convergence in $L^{2}$ implies almost evrywhere convergence for a subsequence.

Comment: Yeah that I know but How to show that $\phi f \in L^2(\mu)$?

Comment: There is no need to prove that $\phi f \in L^{2}(\mu)$